How to query QuestDB time based window function
I'm trying to translate this query from DuckDB to QuestDB:
SELECT
    timestamp,
    symbol,
    price,
    first_value(price) OVER (
        partition by symbol
        ORDER BY timestamp ASC
        RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 3 seconds preceding and current row
    ) AS first_price
FROM trades
WHERE
    timestamp >= '2024-08-22T14:15:29.206'
LIMIT 40;

Getting error:
'preceding' or 'following' expected

How can I use time-bound window functions in QuestDB?
